# Real use of Physical Address Extension (PAE)

Tags: memory-address

I'm a beginner. I came across an article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Though I could partially understand it, I couldn't understand the practical advantage of increasing the physical address. Could anyone kindly explain it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the physical address space beyond 32 bits allows the operating system to access more than 4GB of memory. However, the virtual address space (pointer size) is still 32 bits, and applications need to use special APIs to change where their virtual address space addressed. PAE was a stopgap to allow applications to use more than 4GB of memory on a 32-bit processor.

There is no practical use for PAE today with the widespread implementation of x86-64, which has 64-bit pointers.